The dual space of Hölder Spaces
The Hölder Space is defined by
$$
\mathscr{C}^\alpha(\mathbf{R}^n) \equiv \Bigl\{f\in\mathscr{C}(\mathbf{R}^n); \|f\|_\alpha=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}+\|f\|_\infty<\infty\Bigr\}
$$
for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, by the theory of Besov spaces we have
$$
\mathscr{C}^\alpha(\mathbf{R}^n)\cong B_{\infty,\infty}^\alpha(\mathbf R^n).
$$
In the Theory of Function Spaces by Hans Triebel, we have
$$
\overline{\mathcal{S} (\mathbf{R}^n)}^{B_{p,q}^s}\cong B_{p',q'}^{-s}(\mathbf R^n).
$$
Since Schwartz function are not dense in $B_{\infty,\infty}^\alpha(\mathbf R^n)$, we can not find the dual space of Hölder space by the theorem above.
There are some results of Hölder space $\mathscr{C}^\alpha(\Omega)$, like On the Dual of Besov Spaces, Tosinobu. but assumed that $\Omega$ is bounded (or $\Omega$ is a compace metric space).
Hence, I wonder what the dual space of Hölder space is.

Can you please clarify precisely what your question is? It is extremely unclear what you are looking for at the moment.

@DeanMiller Sorry, I mean, I want to know what the dual space of Hölder space is.

My suggestion would be to rewrite your question to make it clear what you are asking about. At the moment there is no question mark and you need to read all the way until the bottom to find out what your question is. Perhaps add a sentence at the start briefly stating that you are interested in what the dual of a Hölder space is. Then you can expand on that main point in the rest of the question. This will give your question a better chance of being reopened.
